# I have an issue with printing paths from environment variables in windows 11

Tags: java, windows-11, environment-variables

So I tried to install `javabridge` for a project that I have with Weka. By doing this I discovered that I can not print the paths from environment variables when I tried to create a `CLASSPATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables.

For example, I write `echo %CLASSPATH%` in terminal and the output is just `%CLASSPATH%`. I also tried `set` and `setx` in terminal. And I did it manually in the advanced settings of environment variables, they are saved and all but still `echo %...%`  doesn't work.

I tried to run a `Test.java` file too, it compiled to `.class` but `javac Test` did not work, so I could not run `print "Hello World"`. I suspect that is a problem with the environment variables or something. I run `java --version` and `javac --version`, it understands it and tells me the version `17 lts` and other details. I don't know what to do.

Comment: You are mixing Windows CMD commands with linux/unix bash commands. Maybe try `export` to show you the current environment variables in a bash session.

Comment: What's your output from `set` ?

Comment: Is just a command to to set the CLASSPATH variable it saw me that it was successful and saved

Comment: my mistake the set it opened weka but it has a problem the java compiler i dont know yet

Comment: @ΠαύλοςΜηντσόπουλος I mean, add the output of running `set` to your question so we can confirm that the variables have been set correctly. Make sure you remove any sensitive info